# Serial Numbering in a group in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a list of about 90 000 products and about 2000 suppliers. Each of the product should get a unique product code, our company does this in this format : `First 2 letters of the suppliers name, 5 digit suppliers number and a 5 digit product number in that group.`
I need to be able to do this in sql (preference: `MS ACCESS 2013`) or `SQL Server`.

Here is what I want:

```
product_code     suppliers_code       suppliers_name     product_name
PA0009100001     00091                Pardaen NV         product 1
PA0009100002     00091                Pardaen NV         product BB
PA0009100003     00091                Pardaen NV         product CC
HU1007300001     10073                Husqverma          product 2
WI6703300001     67033                Willy Lamot        product 3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *,
      [product_code] = CONCAT(LEFT(suppliers_name,2), suppliers_code,
                              RIGHT('0000' + CAST(rn AS VARCHAR(5)),5)) 
FROM (SELECT *,
             rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY suppliers_code ORDER BY product_name)
      FROM table_name ) AS sub;
```

If you are using lower version than `SQL Server 2012` use `+` to concatenate string.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/449195)**</kbd>

Comment: nitpicking: `row_number()` is available form MS SQL-Server 2008, not 2012

Comment: but concat is from 2012+

Comment: @DesterDezzods Probably after some changes. I have no access to `MS Access` so I could not check it.

Comment: I don't think `ROW_NUMBER()` is avaialbe in `MS Access`. Seach this site. There are solution to that for 'MS Access'

Answer (score 0):

In Access you could use:

```
Select 
    UCase(Left([suppliers_name], 2)) & [suppliers_code] &
        Format((Select Count(*) From YourTable As T 
            Where T.suppliers_name = YourTable.suppliers_name 
            And T.suppliers_code = YourTable.suppliers_code 
            And T.product_code >= YourTable.product_name), "00000")
        As [product_name] 
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. product_code is not a number, its a combination of other fields